# React App failes using NodeJS : Error: spawn cmd ENOENT at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, exception, npm

I'm trying to run a React App with NPM under windows using the following commands :

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app hello-world
cd hello-world/
npm start
```

But i get the following error:

```
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:442:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:255:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:442:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\X220\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-10T10_32_09_262Z-debug.log
```

I've tried to replace the node version but it didn't help.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Updated : 
Node version : v12.2.0
NPM version : 6.9.0

Comment: Can you post your node.js version, react.js version etc?

Comment: Also check if system32 is added under system env path?

Comment: @ KiranMathewMohan :Updated.